# EOF to file on remote host

Tags: bash, shell, sh, eof

I need to "cat" a text inside shell script to remote machine via ssh.
This is required for simplicity, so i don't need to keep extra file.

For instance

```
#!/bin/sh
VAR="some"
VAR1="something"

cat << EOF
apple
green
tree
EOF   ---> cat to file.txt on remote machine

do some command
do some command1
exit 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this if you're generating file content in runtime:

```
cat <<EOF | ssh remote 'cat - > /tmp/my_remote_file.txt'
apple
green
tree
EOF
```

Or simply use scp if file is static.

Comment: can omit the `-` - enough the `cat > /somefile` :)

Comment: Yes, it does work with test sample, thank you! But my real thing gives error - cat: /tmp/viewgpu: No such file or directory   The script is http://pastebin.com/zkNNdsg4
So script inside heredoc start executing on local machine (which not required), need only transfer content to remote PC

Answer (score 1):

Just want to note for everyone. Above example works fine for plain text, but if heredoc includes variables then substitution will take place. So important to protect heredoc phrase with single quotes to keep everything intact
For example

```
cat <<'EOF' | ssh remote 'cat - > /tmp/my_remote_file.txt'
host=$(uname -a)
echo $host
EOF
```

host variable won't be substituted with actual hostname.
As reference (paragraph 19-7) http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html

Comment: If you using bash, is better using `$(uname -a)` instead of `\`uname -a\``. And in your question, you didn't say anything about the "variables" inside of "heredoc"... third, you probably mean `echo $host` in your example code...